# Multistore - Magento 2 Setup

Tags: multistore, magento-2.0, stores, setup

I tried these steps, but nothing happened. I got 500 internal server error
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-and-configure-multistore-magento-2/

I have 3 domains.

The main is **`beste.nl`**. The others are **`fejie.nl`** and **`pacats.nl`**.

Codes:

```
beste.nl = beste
fejie.nl = fejie
pacats.nl = pacats
```

I just copied the **`index.php`** of **`beste.nl`** and pasted into **`fejie.nl`**, and using this following code:

> $params = $_SERVER;
>   $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'fejie';
>   $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
>   $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
>   $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
>   $bootstrap->run($app)

I just copied the **`.htaccess`** of **`beste.nl`** and pasted into **`fejie.nl`**, and using this following code:

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)fejie.nl
>
>   RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:fejie]
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)fejie.nl
>
>   RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the .htaccess should be sufficient with Magento 2. No need to update the index.php. 
In the .htaccess file make sure to add

```
SetEnvIf Host .*example.com.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=yourcode.yourdomain.com
SetEnvIf Host .*example.com.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

And

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example\.com
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:frenchsite.example.com]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example\.com
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

Do not forget the backslash.