# Magento 2. Issue with correct setup of stores (nginx)

Tags: magento2, nginx

I have three stores:
http://www.nl.mysite.nl
http://www.gb.mysite.nl
http://www.us.mysite.nl

As soon as i type them they all redirect to the default website: http://www.mysite.nl/default

When i type the code of the respective stores after http://www.mysite.nl/ i am redirected to the store in question; for instance, by typing http://www.mysite.nl/nl_store i am redirected to http://www.nl.mysite.nl/nl_store

Any ideas on how to fix this, in a way that the three stores do not redirect to the default, but to the themselves?

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you share the config for the base URL and for nginx, please? Do you use Varnish?

Comment: have you created separate folders for your stores ? in your magento root directory ?

Comment: I do not use Varnish. This is basically what I did: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_nginx.html Base url's are ok (double check in databases) and for nginx, the config is like in the previous shared link

Comment: Are there any specific files you would like to take a look at?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multistore - Magento 2 Setup](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127847/multistore-magento-2-setup)

Comment: The errors was indeed in a duplicate of the nginx.conf (one in /etc/nginx/ and the second one in the Magento root); Magento did not know which one he should take :) In my case I did not make any edit on .htacess and index.php